# Group by In SQL query is not working well in my query

Tags: sql-server

[image: result set]I have 3 tables . Orders, OrderLines, BillLines. The primary key of Orders is a FK in the 2 other tables.

I am trying to query the client debit and credit amount.
The Action table just describe the type of the transaction 
The Subindex table stores the clients names and ids

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders](
    [OrderID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Ordertype] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Orderdate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [transactionNo] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DocumentNo] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ordernote] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Profittax] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [DescDR] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [DescCR] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [ActionsID] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [SubIndexesID] [smallint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Orders] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [OrderID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Orders]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Orders_dbo.Actions_ActionsID] FOREIGN KEY([ActionsID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Actions] ([ActionsID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Orders] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Orders_dbo.Actions_ActionsID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Orders]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Orders_dbo.SubIndexes_SubIndexesID] FOREIGN KEY([SubIndexesID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[SubIndexes] ([SubIndexesID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Orders] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Orders_dbo.SubIndexes_SubIndexesID]
GO

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orderlines](
    [OrderlinesID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [OrderID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Qin] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Qout] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Price] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [currency] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Discount] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [VAT] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [ItemsID] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Total] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Vatvalue] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Net] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Orderlines] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [OrderlinesID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Orderlines] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Total]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Orderlines] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Vatvalue]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Orderlines] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [Net]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Orderlines]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Orderlines_dbo.Items_ItemsID] FOREIGN KEY([ItemsID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Items] ([ItemsID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Orderlines] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Orderlines_dbo.Items_ItemsID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Orderlines]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Orderlines_dbo.Orders_OrderID] FOREIGN KEY([OrderID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Orderlines] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Orderlines_dbo.Orders_OrderID]
GO

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BillLines](
    [BillLinesID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [VALIN] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [VALOut] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [OrderID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SubIndexesID] [smallint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.BillLines] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [BillLinesID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BillLines]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.BillLines_dbo.Orders_OrderID] FOREIGN KEY([OrderID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BillLines] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.BillLines_dbo.Orders_OrderID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BillLines]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.BillLines_dbo.SubIndexes_SubIndexesID] FOREIGN KEY([SubIndexesID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[SubIndexes] ([SubIndexesID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BillLines] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.BillLines_dbo.SubIndexes_SubIndexesID]
GO

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Actions](
    [ActionsID] [smallint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Actionname] [nvarchar](4000) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Actions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ActionsID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SubIndexes](
    [SubIndexesID] [smallint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Subname] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [AccountIndexID] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Contacttype] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [phones] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [fax] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [email] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [address] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [zip] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Website] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.SubIndexes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SubIndexesID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SubIndexes]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.SubIndexes_dbo.AccountIndexes_AccountIndexID] FOREIGN KEY([AccountIndexID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AccountIndexes] ([AccountIndexID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SubIndexes] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.SubIndexes_dbo.AccountIndexes_AccountIndexID]
GO
```

My Query is

```
select distinct
               o.OrderID , 
               s.Subname as subindexname,  
               o.SubIndexesID as Subindex ,
               sum(ol.Qout * (ol.Price - ol.Discount)* (1+(ol.VAT/100)-(o.Profittax/100))+ bl.VALOut) -iif(o.ActionsID between 3 and 4, o.DescDR+o.DescCR,0) as Debit ,
               sum(ol.Qin * (ol.Price - ol.Discount )* (1+(ol.VAT/100)-(o.Profittax/100))+ bl.VALIN)-iif(o.ActionsID not between 3 and 4,o.DescCR + o.DescDR,0) as Credit

from Orders o 
     inner join 
     Orderlines ol  on o.OrderID = ol.OrderID 
     inner join 
     BillLines bl on o.OrderID = bl.OrderID 
     inner join 
     SubIndexes s on o.SubIndexesID= s.SubIndexesID
group by o.OrderID, 
         o.ActionsID, 
         o.SubIndexesID,
         o.DescCR,
         o.DescDR,
         ol.Qout,
         ol.Qin,
         s.Subname,
         s.SubIndexesID, 
         ol.VAT, 
         ol.Price, 
         ol.Discount
having o.ActionsID=2 
       or o.ActionsID=3 
       or o.ActionsID=4 
       or o.ActionsID=5
```

I want to show the debit and the credit in one row even I have multiple orderlines for one order.

Comment: Input and expected output?

Comment: Thanks for replying, inputs are quantity out in sales, price, discount on each item, discount for whole order, received money, tax on each item, tax on all order.   The out puts are how much money received which is credit, the value on the client which is debit.

Comment: Why do you need 2GB of space to store someone's phone number? Why do you need 2GB of space to store what currency someone uses? Why do you need 2GB of space to store *any* of those values...?

Comment: By "Input and Expected Output" xXx was asking your to provide some sample data for both.

Comment: Thanks for replying , I dont know that the size is 2 GB i just made the code by MVC code first, any advice ?

Comment: OrderID column is using in the GROUP BY statement, for this reason, the different OrderID values will be separated into different rows. However, you can gather the OrderID columns with help of the STRING_AGG function so the OrderID will be shown like (1,2,3,4) and then you can remove this column in the GROUP BY statement

Comment: *"i just made the code by MVC code first"* MVC wouldn't create every column as an `nvarchar(MAX)` unless you told it to.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice , i will change it in my application

Comment: Dear xXx and Dale ii edited my question and put an image, thanks

Comment: please look at order 43

Comment: Dear Esat i removed the order id from the query but the same result

Comment: Could you remove ol.Qout,ol.Qin,s.SubIndexesID,ol.VAT,ol.Price,ol.Discount columns in theGROUP BY statement. It may help you to overcome this issue. Because these columns are using in the aggregation and if you don t need to grouping you can remove them.

Comment: I really thank you lot,it successfully grouped by but the credit value is duplicated

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to include all cols in Group-by in Select as well:

```
select distinct
               o.OrderID , 
               s.Subname as subindexname,  
               o.SubIndexesID as Subindex ,              
               o.ActionsID,          
               o.DescCR,
               o.DescDR,
               ol.Qout,
               ol.Qin,
               s.Subname,
               s.SubIndexesID, 
               ol.VAT, 
               ol.Price, 
               ol.Discount
               sum(ol.Qout * (ol.Price - ol.Discount)* (1+(ol.VAT/100)-(o.Profittax/100))+ bl.VALOut) -iif(o.ActionsID between 3 and 4, o.DescDR+o.DescCR,0) as Debit ,
               sum(ol.Qin * (ol.Price - ol.Discount )* (1+(ol.VAT/100)-(o.Profittax/100))+ bl.VALIN)-iif(o.ActionsID not between 3 and 4,o.DescCR + o.DescDR,0) as Credit

from Orders o 
     inner join 
     Orderlines ol  on o.OrderID = ol.OrderID 
     inner join 
     BillLines bl on o.OrderID = bl.OrderID 
     inner join 
     SubIndexes s on o.SubIndexesID= s.SubIndexesID
group by o.OrderID, 
         o.ActionsID, 
         o.SubIndexesID,
         o.DescCR,
         o.DescDR,
         ol.Qout,
         ol.Qin,
         s.Subname,
         s.SubIndexesID, 
         ol.VAT, 
         ol.Price, 
         ol.Discount
having o.ActionsID=2 
       or o.ActionsID=3 
       or o.ActionsID=4 
       or o.ActionsID=5
```